# Kubuntu live cd via PXE on server 2012r2

Tags: linux, nfs, windows-server-2012-r2, kubuntu, pxe

I am attempting to PXE boot the kubuntu live CD ( prepped to be booted on a usb drive, then files placed on a NFS share with root acces read/write to everyone )

the PXE boot menu component launched is configured as follows:

```
LABEL Kubuntu

    menu label Kubuntu

    # Load the correct kernel

    kernel pxelinux.cfg/kubuntu/casper/vmlinuz.efi

    # Boot options

    append priority=low vga=normal initrd=/pxelinux.cfg/kubuntu/casper
/initrd.lz boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.25:/kubuntu nosplash --
```

- the kernel loads properly
- initrd.lz loads up properly
- client succesfully contacts the server and NFS share and continues

this is where a couple mount errors occur and the boot sequence gets halted.

- it fails to mount /dev on /root/dev ( the NFS share is read/write ) 
  a bunch of errors bellow it about current directory on the same filesystem as the root
- no init found

then bussybox and prompt

edit: 
I have attempted a new append in the boot-options using kubuntu 15.10 files and 16.04 using: append initrd=/pxelinux.cfg/kubuntu/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.25:/kubuntu file=preseed/kubuntu.seed locale=en_US root=/dev/nfs quiet splash --

using that.., I get a quick kubuntu splash screen which is followed by what seems to be a kernel error described in bug : https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79261

Comment: The NFS share doesn’t have to be writable. In fact, it shouldn’t be. A CD/DVD isn’t either. That being said, did you try with other Ubuntu variants?

Comment: I haven't, in my earlier attempts the NFS was indeed read only.., when attempting to trouble shoot the share I made it read/write to make sure there could be nothing on the NFS end prohibiting it. I have not yet tried a different distribution though

Comment: I'll try with Kubuntu later. I have Ubuntu and Mint running with PXE.

Comment: Works for me. It would appear your problem is NFS-related. How exactly did you set up the NFS share?

Comment: simply enough, shared a folder on the D drive using - right click-properties-NFS-share and set the permission to everyone to full acces ( read only before troubleshooting steps )

Comment: I see. I’m not familiar with Windows’ NFS server, so you’ll have to wait for someone else. I’ve added some tags to attract others. One last question: Did you verify the NFS share works on Linux?

Comment: I have verified it works, it manages to do the first (few?) mounts successfully.., which would indicate the NFS is working

Comment: I have attempted a new append in the boot-options using kubuntu 15.10 files and 16.04 using: append initrd=/pxelinux.cfg/kubuntu/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.25:/kubuntu file=preseed/kubuntu.seed locale=en_US root=/dev/nfs quiet splash --

using that.., I get a quick kubuntu splash screen which is followed by what seems to be a kernel error described in bug : https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79261